# Listener on html button disabled attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to detect when a button's disabled attribute changes from disabled to false ? Like an event or something ?

Comment: Why do you mean by a button's disabled attribute changes to false?

Comment: To enable it i.e make it click-able.

Comment: Having `disabled="false"` in the HTML tag will make it disabled. Having `disabled` itself makes it state disabled.

Comment: How do you disabled your button? `<<= You should then be able to know when this 'event' occurs`

Comment: A. Wolff So and event that detects an attribute change doesn't exist ?

Comment: @Joseph there is no cross browser event like that

Comment: @A. Wolff if you put that comment as an answer i will gladly accept it. Otherwise I'll flag it . Thank you :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) but that's a killer performance and not really wide support. You could use some CSS trick too on browsers which support it, as here: http://jsfiddle.net/zxAPm/

But your best bet is when you swicth state of any `input`, trigger custom event or call directly your logic/function:

http://jsfiddle.net/cj2qF/

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript

```
document.getElementsByTagName("BUTTON")[0].hasAttribute("disabled");
```

Comment: Friend , i want to detect the change from disabled to enabled (event) !! Your code will find me the first button that has a disabled attribute .

Comment: @Joseph There is no such event, no native one. You could use some observer or even set a property setter but usually, better is when you disbale/enable button, then trigger custom event or call logic directly. So what makes change specific button state in your code?

Comment: hasAttribute returns a boolean, you can use it in a if statement to check whether your button is disabled or not as per this link : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_hasattributes.asp

Comment: @Steve But this is not the question here

Comment: @Joseph On modern browsers, you could use a trick with CSS animation and pseudo classes `:disabled/:enabled` firing an animation and then bind animationend or start event, but that's like bringing gun at pillow fight

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, you can remove `disabled` attribute not false

```
if($("button").has("[disabled]") == true){
 //your code
  $("button").prop("disabled", false);
}
```